# OpenGL - Generate plane from normal vector

Tags: opengl, vector, normals, voxel

I am trying to make the generation of voxel/cubes more efficient.
First of all I calculate on the cpu which faces are not hidden by other voxels/cubes.
Than I send the voxel/cube position and the face normal to the gpu / the vertex, geometry and fragment shader.
So now I want simply to generate in the geometry shader a triangle strip from the **voxel position** and **face normal**.
But now I have problems to calculate the four new vertices from these two informations, I can't find a solution without if and else functions.
And since I use backface culling I have to pay attention to the order I emit the vertices from the shader, too.
Whats the most efficient way to solve my problem?
Or have someone a better idea than my approach?

The normal vector can only have 6 states, for each face of a cube:
(0, 0, 1) Front
(0, 0, -1) Back
(0, 1, 0) Up
(0, -1, 0) Down
(1, 0, 0) Right
(-1, 0, 0) Left

Comment: Hint: The normal is the negative inverse of the surface.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Have you considered extending a point out in the direction of the cross-product between the normal and each of the Cartesian axes? That should give you 3 co-planar displacements (one of which will always be a zero vector given the 6 normals you listed) without any if/else logic.